# How to reliably check whether Windows Update is enabled using C#?

Tags: c#, com, windows-update

I tried to check if Windows Update is enabled. I added a reference to c:\windows\system32\wuapi.dll on Windows 7 x64 Ultimate and wrote this code

```
using WUApiLib;
public Boolean IsWindowsUpdateEnabled()
{
    var updates = new AutomaticUpdatesClass();
    return updates.ServiceEnabled;
}
```

The code fails to build. I get the following error:

> Error 1   The type 'WUApiLib.AutomaticUpdatesClass' has no constructors
>   defined
>   Error 2   Interop type 'WUApiLib.AutomaticUpdatesClass' cannot
>   be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.
>   Error 3   'WUApiLib.AutomaticUpdatesClass' does not contain a definition
>   for 'ServiceEnabled' and no extension method 'ServiceEnabled'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'WUApiLib.AutomaticUpdatesClass'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: Have you tried using wuapi.dll located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 ?

Comment: @SuperOli: If hes on 32 bits he will get automatically redirected there.

Comment: See [Determining the Current Version of WUA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385815%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: When i add reference via VS 2010 i see the following path: c:\windows\SysWowo64\wuapi.dll under the COM tab. But it gives the same error. I have also tried manuall adding reference by browsing to c:\windows\system32\wuapi.dll but the result is the same. I have V2 of Wuapi.dll but i think it should not be the problem. I have seen people do the same for V1 of the dll which is found on Windows XP Sp2 but i am targeting Windows 2008 or Later OSes only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Visual Studio project References list, find the WUApiLib reference and change its "Embed Interop Types" to "False".

Comment: +1 for the idea.
will try your solution and post results here. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked. If you could only answer one more questions of mine, please?
1. Why setting "Embed" settings to False makes it working?
Thank you for the answer and will greatly appreciate if you could write a few lines to answer my noobs-ter questions. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could query the registry to see?

```
public string Read(string KeyName)
{
    // Opening the registry key
    RegistryKey rk = baseRegistryKey ;
    // Open a subKey as read-only
    RegistryKey sk1 = rk.OpenSubKey(subKey);
    // If the RegistrySubKey doesn't exist -> (null)
    if ( sk1 == null )
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        try 
        {
            // If the RegistryKey exists I get its value
            // or null is returned.
            return (string)sk1.GetValue(KeyName.ToUpper());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // AAAAAAAAAAARGH, an error!
            ShowErrorMessage(e, "Reading registry " + KeyName.ToUpper());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

[source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)

And the locations to look:

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Registry-Keys-Tweaking-Windows-Update-Part1.html

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
>   ...
>
> The first of these keys is the AUOptions key. This DWORD value can be
>   assigned a value of either 2, 3, 4, or 5. A value of 2 indicates that
>   the agent should notify the user prior to downloading updates. A value
>   of 3 indicates that updates will be automatically downloaded and the
>   user will be notified of installation. A value of 4 indicates that
>   updates should be automatically downloaded and installed according to
>   a schedule. For this option to work, the ScheduledInstallDay and
>   ScheduledInstallTime keys must also be set. I will talk more about
>   those keys later on. Finally, a value of 5 indicates that automatic
>   updates are required, but can be configured by end users.

Etc.

Though it might be different if the settings are done by the Group Policy.

More info here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328010

Comment: +1 for the approach.
Will that work on 32 and 64 bit versions of Windows 2008 R2 and later Oses? Can i rely on this at Windows 2008, 2008 R2 2012 and Windows 7 x86 and x64 bit systems. I am sorry i did not clarify this in my original question. But i do get the gist. Thank you.